# How do I export NHibernate schema for SQLite if I have dots in the schema name?

Tags: unit-testing, sqlite, fluent-nhibernate, nunit, nhibernate-mapping

I'm trying to set up SQLite for unit testing with Fluent NHibernate [as shown here](http://www.dotnetguy.co.uk/post/2009/10/20/sqlite-nunit-fluent-nhibernate-test-your-data-access-layer) but the table names isn't being generated as I expected.

Some tables have schemas with dots inside which seems to break the generation. *(Dots works perfectly well with Microsoft SQL Server which I have in my production environment.)*

Example:

```
[Foo.Bar.Schema].[TableName]
```

Result:

```
TestFixture failed: System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException : SQLite error
unknown database Foo
```

How do I instruct SQLite to translate the dots to underscores or something so I can run my unit tests?

(I've tried adding brackets to the schema names with no success)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a convention
http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Conventions

*UPDATED

```
public static class PrivatePropertyHelper
    {
        // from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565734/is-it-possible-to-set-private-property-via-reflection
        public static T GetPrivatePropertyValue<T>(this object obj, string propName)
        {
            if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
            PropertyInfo pi = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            if (pi == null) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("propName", string.Format("Property {0} was not found in Type {1}", propName, obj.GetType().FullName));
            return (T)pi.GetValue(obj, null);
        }
    }

public class CustomTableNameConvention : IClassConvention
{
    // Use this to set schema to specific value
    public void Apply(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Instances.IClassInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Schema("My_NEw_Schema");
        instance.Table(instance.EntityType.Name.CamelToUnderscoreLower());
    }


    // Use this to alter the existing schema value.
    // note that Schema is a private property and you need reflection to get it
    public void Apply(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Instances.IClassInstance instance)
    {          
        instance.Schema(instance.GetPrivatePropertyValue<string>("Schema").Replace(".", "_"));
        instance.Table(instance.EntityType.Name.CamelToUnderscoreLower());
    }
}
```

You must use only one of he Apply methods.

*UPDATE 2
I don't know I would recommend this but if you like to experiment this seems to work. Even more reflection :)

```
    public static void SetSchemaValue(this object obj, string schema)
    {

        var mapping_ref  = obj.GetType().GetField("mapping", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(obj);

        var mapping = mapping_ref as ClassMapping;
        if (mapping != null)
        {
            mapping.Schema = schema;
        }
    }


    public void Apply(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Instances.IClassInstance instance)
    {
        var schema = instance.GetPrivatePropertyValue<string>("Schema");
        if (schema == null)
        {
            instance.Schema("My_New_Schema");
        }
        else
        {
            instance.SetSchemaValue("My_New_Schema");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have the schema name set in the ClassMap. The conventions does not apply if the value is specifically set. I noticed this in the [source here](http://www.symbolsource.org/Caliper/Metadata/Default/Project/Fluent-NHibernate/1.0RTM/Release/All/FluentNHibernate/FluentNHibernate/Conventions/Instances/ClassInstance.cs).

Comment: If you apply instance.Schema("Something") it will definitively override the existing value. See updated example above.

Comment: Thank you. I tried a similar approach with instance.Schema((IClassInspector)instance).Schema.Replace('.', '_')) but it seems like instance.Schema() won't set the property if it's already set. I can get the name and replace but it won't override the schema in the mapping.

Comment: If you are feeling adventurous but try the updated code above. :)

Comment: Your solution works but I ended up simplified my schemas since it wasn't any real trade-off. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Changing the schema was the better way for sure