# JSON Serializer object with internal properties

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have class with some internal properties and I would like to serialize them into json as well. How can I accomplish this?
For example

```
public class Foo
{
    internal int num1 { get; set; }
    internal double num2 { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Description))
            return Description;

        return base.ToString();
    }
}
```

Saving it using

```
Foo f = new Foo();
f.Description = "Foo Example";
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All };

 string jsonOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(f, Formatting.Indented, settings);

 using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("json_file.json"))
 {
     sw.WriteLine(jsonOutput);
 }
```

I get

```
{  
"$type": "SideSlopeTest.Foo, SideSlopeTest",
"Description": "Foo Example"
}
```

Comment: Usually internal properties are not intended to be leaving the boundaries of the current assembly and thus being serialized. Why would you need to do that? If you want a proper JSON representation you might need a DTO to map your internal/private stuff to and then serialize.

Comment: +1 what @DarinDimitrov said. But if you really want to do it, I believe you need to subclass `DefaultContractResolver` to make it look at non-public properties as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON.Net: Force serialization of all private fields and all fields in sub-classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106986/json-net-force-serialization-of-all-private-fields-and-all-fields-in-sub-classe)

Comment: Just mark them with the [`[JsonProperty()]`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) attribute.

Comment: if the class is also internal mark it with `[JsonObject()]`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Mark the internal properties to be serialized with the [`[JsonProperty]`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) attribute:

```
public class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty]
    internal int num1 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    internal double num2 { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Description))
            return Description;

        return base.ToString();
    }
}
```

And then later, to test:

```
Foo f = new Foo();
f.Description = "Foo Example";
f.num1 = 101;
f.num2 = 202;
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All };

var jsonOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(f, Formatting.Indented, settings);

Console.WriteLine(jsonOutput);
```

I get the following output:

```
{
  "$type": "Tile.JsonInternalPropertySerialization.Foo, Tile",
  "num1": 101,
  "num2": 202.0,
  "Description": "Foo Example"
}
```

(Where "Tile.JsonInternalPropertySerialization" and "Tile" are namespace and assembly names I am using).

**As an aside**, when using `TypeNameHandling`, do take note of this caution from the [Newtonsoft docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm):

> TypeNameHandling should be used with caution when your application deserializes JSON from an external source. Incoming types should be validated with a custom SerializationBinder when deserializing with a value other than None.

For a discussion of why this may be necessary, see *[TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954/3744182)* and and *[External json vulnerable because of Json.Net TypeNameHandling auto?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49038055/3744182)*.

Comment: I just deleted my answer saying that internal properties are not accessible outside the assembly because this is news to me. How is a serializer able to access these across assemblies? Is this not somewhat of a security problem?

Comment: @esmoore68 - The serializer uses reflection.  See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565734/is-it-possible-to-set-private-property-via-reflection and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191282/isnt-accessing-private-fields-and-properties-due-to-reflection-a-security-issue.

Comment: in addition to @dbc answer, what is reported is still valid also for internal-visibility classes and private-visibility (nested) classes