# Newtonsoft.Json serialization returns empty json object

Tags: asp.net, json, json.net

I have list of objects of following class:

```
public class Catagory
{
    int catagoryId;
    string catagoryNameHindi;
    string catagoryNameEnglish;
    List<Object> subCatagories;
    public Catagory(int Id, string NameHindi, string NameEng,List<Object> l)
    {
        this.catagoryId = Id;
        this.catagoryNameHindi = NameHindi;
        this.catagoryNameEnglish = NameEng;
        this.subCatagories = l;
    }
}

  public class SubCatagory
{
    int subCatagoryId { get; set; }
    string subCatNameHindi { get; set; }
    string subCatNameEng { get; set; }

    public SubCatagory(int Id, string NameHindi, string NameEng)
    {
        this.subCatagoryId = Id;
        this.subCatNameEng = NameEng;
        this.subCatNameHindi = NameHindi;
    }
}
```

when I am converting this list to json string by using Newtonsoft.Json it returns array of empty objects.

```
  string json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
```

I am getting following result.

> [{},{},{},{},{}]

Please help me regarding this problem.

Comment: Are you sure the list is not the list of the null Objects. As you have declared `Parameterzied` constructor. If you want to create empty object then you have to manually declare the `empty` constructor in class.

Comment: yeah there are no null objects in the list

Comment: I was having the same problem using the Jackson library. Making the fields public solved the problem there too.

Comment: Not having public properties was exactly my issue as well.

Comment: Properties marked internal are a similar issue.  See this post for ideas:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873755/json-serializer-object-with-internal-properties

Answer (score 142, accepted):

By default, NewtonSoft.Json will only serialize public members, so make your fields public:

```
public class Catagory
{
    public int catagoryId;
    public string catagoryNameHindi;
    public string catagoryNameEnglish;
    public List<Object> subCatagories;

    public Catagory(int Id, string NameHindi, string NameEng, List<Object> l)
    {
        this.catagoryId = Id;
        this.catagoryNameHindi = NameHindi;
        this.catagoryNameEnglish = NameEng;
        this.subCatagories = l;
    }
}
```

If for some reason you really don't want to make your fields public, you can instead decorate them with the [JsonPropertyAttribute](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm) to allow them to be serialized and deserialized:

```
[JsonProperty]
int catagoryId;
```

This attribute also allows specifying other options, such as specifying the property name to use when serializing/deserializing:

```
[JsonProperty("categoryId")]
int Category;
```

Comment: Public members of the class Is not the best solution. Does Exist other better solution?

Comment: @IgnacioChiazzo Yes, you should be able to use the [`JsonPropertyAttribute`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm) to indicate that a non-public field or property should be serialized: `[JsonProperty]private int categoryId;`

Comment: @JLRishe - You should add your comment as an answer as this is now how I do it rather than making everything public

Comment: @ChrisHammond Updated my answer.

Comment: pulling my hair out for an hour wondering why this didn't work for one class but did for another; overlooked that I did not declare my properties as `public`!

Comment: Someone changed from "public" -> "internal" a few properties and this became a nightmare! Thank you! Good to know...

Comment: I would say I pulled my hair out for 2 hours, my data was all set to internal as well.

Answer (score 19):

You could also decorate your class to serialize all members you want without having to specify [JsonProperty] for each of them.

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptOut)]
public class Catagory {
    ...
}
```

The *MemberSerialization* enum allows you to specify what members you want to serialize:

- *MemberSerialization.OptOut*: All public members are serialized.
- *MemberSerialization.OptIn*: Only members marked with JsonPropertyAttribute or DataMemberAttribute are serialized.
- *MemberSerialization.Fields*: All public and private members are serialized.

Comment: it really saved my day

Comment: This solution just saved me.  I have never had to do this before, and have no idea why I suddenly need to do it now... but I won't forget it.

Answer (score 15):

Another cause of this problem--the class I was attempting to serialize derived from a base class that had the `[DataContract]` attribute, but the derived class lacked this attribute.  Once I added `[DataContract]` to the derived class and `[DataMember]` to all of the public properties of the derived class it began working immediately.

Comment: A similar thing seemed to happen to me, except with an inner class (outer had [DataContract], but inner did not). The same solution fixed it.

Answer (score 10):

A different problem in my case,
It appears if you mark a class as `[DataContract]` then the properties to be serialized need to be marked `[DataMember]` and also should be Public.

In my case, I was migrating from WCF to web API , so didnt require any of DataContract or DataMember, so I removed all and it got serialised fine.