# Convert object content to json string

Tags: c#, json, reflection

I'm using reflection to deserialize object from binary stream ("objType=SM.Backend.Entities.Erp.CodeListBase"):

```
var methodInfo = typeof(SM.Core.Serializator).GetMethod("DeserializeCache");
var genericMethod = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(objType);
var _objItem = genericMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { _streamedData });
```

It works. If I inspect _objItem in Locals window it looks like:[_objItem](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByTr5TBi-A13LUZTeG1raVZJaTA)

Now i would like to export _objItem content to json string:

```
var jsonString=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_objItem, Formatting.Indented);
```

But result is empty: "[]". If I do the same for other objects it works.
I guess for this object it doesn't work because it is complex type(nested):

```
SM.Backend.Entities.Erp.CodeListBase{SM.Backend.Entities.Erp.CodeList<SM.Backend.Entities.Erp.MaterialType>}.
```

Any idea how to extract the content from locals to json string? Should I convert object to different type first?

If I change _objItem to be iList of items of type:

```
SM.Backend.Entities.Erp.CodeList<SM.Backend.Entities.Erp.MaterialType>        
SM.Backend.Entities.Erp.CodeList<SM.Backend.Entities.Erp.ProductDescriptionType>
```

...

as you can see here:
[_objItem](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByTr5TBi-A13SkFxay1ma1BVSDQ)

the result is the same "[]". But collection is not empty.

Comment: SerializeObject((SM.Backend.Entities.Erp.CodeList<SM.Backend.Entities.Erp.MaterialType>)_objItem, Formatting.Indented); could be some problem with type identification.

Comment: By default, NewtonSoft.Json will only serialize public members http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29003215/newtonsoft-json-serialization-returns-empty-json-object

Comment: Thanks. i think all members are public. And idea?

Comment: SM.Backend.Entities.Erp.CodeList<SM.Backend‌​.Entities.Erp.Materi‌​alType> _objItem = genericMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { _streamedData });

//try cast object to correct type or look at my first comment

Comment: But something work fine because "[]" it mean that it detect IEnumerable otherway you will get "{}"

Comment: Casting doesn't help.The result is the same - still [].

Comment: can you create that object without reflection and serialize that. Or are you able to add attribute [JsonProperty]?

Comment: Your `CodeList<T>` type must be some sort of collection, and Json.NET will serialize any non-dictionary collection as a JSON array, as explained [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationguide.htm#Lists).  `"[]"` must be appearing because the collection is empty.

Comment: I have add also picture when _objItem is iList collection. And it is not empty, it is iList collection.