# Allowing Newtonsoft's JsonConvert access to internal getter/setters

Tags: c#, json.net, internal, class-visibility

I have a class with internal getters/setters to prevent the user from accessing this functionality (I'm working with a REST api). However, this also means that JsonConvert doesn't have access to them. How can I allow JsonConvert access to the internal functionality?

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873755/json-serializer-object-with-internal-properties

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to decorate them with the JsonPropertyAttribute.

```
void Main()
{
    var x = new Test();
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x));
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Test 
{
    public Test()
    {
        TestProp = "test";
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    internal string TestProp { get; set; }
}
```

Output: `{"TestProp":"test"}`

Using Linqpad.

Comment: Interesting - this seems to have done the trick - I've been messing about with `InternalsVisibleTo`! Is there a way I don't have to do this for each property that has an internal getter/setter as there are quite a few?

Comment: You can decorate the class with `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.Fields)]`. You can also use a custom contract resolver, as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24107081/5402620