# Couchbase insert empty content to server if I use internal, why?

Tags: c#, .net-core, couchbase

I create a simple insert operation to add the document to the server. My problem is the server has the id and empty content. I create all the staff by tutorial from [Source code](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/3.x/developer/dotnet-2.0/storing.html)

this is source code

```
var document = new Document<Person>
{
  Id = "P1",
  Content = new Person
  {
      FirstName = "John",
      LastName = "Adams",
      Age = 21
  }
};

var result = bucket.Insert(document);
if (result.Success)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Inserted document '{0}'", document.Id);
}
```

that's mine (in a picture I show what I get in a server)

```
IBucket bucket = await ClusterHelper.GetBucketAsync("new_bucket");

var document = new Document<Person>
        {
            Id = "P1",
            Content = new Person
            {
                Name = "John",
                Surname = "Adams",
                Age = 21
            }
        };

        var result = await bucket.InsertAsync(document);
        if (result.Success)
            Console.WriteLine("Inserted document '{0}'", document.Id);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Error this document exist");
```

[image]

I would like to know, Why it doesn't work with an object person? Why it saves empty content? (I take the example from source code, maybe I did something wrong?

**Edit**

```
public class Person
{
    internal string Name { get; set; }
    internal string Surname { get; set; }
    internal int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Some interesting thing if I write the

```
var document = new Document<dynamic>
        {
            Id = "dynamic",
            Content = new
            {
                Name = "John",
                Surname = "Adams",
                Age = 21
            }
        };
```

I take the content but it isn't comfortable( just my meaning)

[image]

Interesting but GET, UPDATE has the same problem. `Get<Person>` always returns `Null` value. WHY couchbase have that strange behavior?

**Important**

The problem with access modification `internal` need to use only public! however why? does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I'm a little confused. It works as you expect when using `dynamic`, but not when using `Person`?

Comment: I found the problem. Do you know why it doesn't work with access modification `Internal`, just `public`, for me it interesting and strange.

Comment: Your `Person` class is internal?

Comment: I added it into the question, you can watch it after **Edit** part (I forgot to change the public class to internal, but if I have any field with internal which I wanna send to the server, it saves empty string

Comment: Okay, I think this might be because of the way the Json serializer works. Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873755/json-serializer-object-with-internal-properties

Comment: Yes, you were right, could you write the answer and I will mark it. Maybe in the future, this information would help someone like me now.